# Updating MySQL Database using MVP Pattern

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, mvp

I'm new to this kind of pattern I'm wondering why I'm getting error

> "cannot convert dbnull to other types"

I know my code doesn't work that's why it's returning some null values on the _view, any help? im getting this on line model.CustomerID = _view.CustomerID;

```
  Model
  public class CustomerModel
  {
            private string _customerid;
            public string CustomerID;
            {
                get { return _customerid; }
                set { _customerid = value; }
            }
            private string _orderstatus;
            public string OrderStatus
            {
                get { return _orderstatus; }
                set { _orderstatus = value; }
            }
            public void UpdateOrderStatus()
            {
                var connSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"];
                {
                    string CN = connSettings.ConnectionString;
                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(CN);
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update customerorders set order_status = @value where customerid = @customerid", conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerid", _customerid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", _orderstatus);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
     }

  Interface
  public interface ICustomer
  {
        void SetPresenter(CustomerPresenter presenter);
        void UpdateCustomerOrderStatus(CustomerModel record);
        string CustomerID { get; set; }
        string OrderStatus { get; set; }
  }

  Presenter
  public class CustomerPresenter
  {
        ICustomer _view;
        CustomerModel _model = new CustomerModel();

        public void CustomerPresenter(ICustomer view)
        {
           _view = view;
        }
        private void updateCustomerOrderStatus(CustomerModel model)
        {
            model.CustomerID = _view.CustomerID;
            model.OrderStatus = _view.OrderStatus;
        }
        public void Save()
        {
            updateCustomerOrderStatus(CustomerModel model)
            this._view.UpdateCustomerOrderStatus(CustomerModel record);
        }
  }

  CustomerForm
  public partial class frmCustomer: Form, ICustomer
  {
        CustomerPresenter _presenter
        public void SetPresenter(CustomerPresenter presenter)
        {
           _presenter = presenter
        }
        public string CustomerID
        {
        get { return this.txtCustomerID.Text; }
        set { txtCustomerID.Text = value; }
        }
        public string OrderStatus
        {
        get { return this.txtOrderStatus.Text; }
        set { txtOrderStatus.Text = value; }
        }
        public void UpdateCustomerOrderStatus(CustomerModel record)
        {
            record.CustomerID = txtCustomerID.Text;
            record.OrderStatus = txtOrderStatus.Text;
        }
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.Save();
        }
  }
```

Comment: At which point in your code are you getting the exception ?

Comment: here  model.CustomerID = _view.CustomerID;

Comment: Your code clearly indicates that `_view` object is declared but not initialised.

Comment: i have edited my post please check, already initialised it but still getting same error now pointed at my Save Event Button.

Answer (score 2):

Your `_view` is now indeed initialized correctly, but `_view.CustomerID` will always be `null` because you don't do anything within the `get` and `set`. So when you try to use the `get` it won't return anything and that's why you get this exception.

Comment: You btw never use: `CustomerModel.UpdateOrderStatus` and you should know that you can adjust `CustomerModel.CustomerID` and `CustomerModel.OrderStatus` directly, instead of the steps between.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code, `_view` is never getting initialised.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: You are only declaring `ICustomer _view;` but never assigning `_view ` with any value.

Comment: you mean i need like this SetViewValues(ICustomer view) {_view = view}?

Comment: Yes, and that should happen before you do `model.CustomerID = _view.CustomerID;`

Comment: i have edited my post please check, already initialised it but still getting same error now pointed at my Save Event Button.

Comment: You have written the constructor accepting ICustomer, but you have not instantiated the class with this constructor.

Comment: in SetPresenter, can you try putting  `_view = presenter.view;` correct the syntax if its wrong, not exactly sure about c# syntax

Comment: i think setpresenter doesn't have view property

Comment: `presenter` is of type CustomerPresenter. It should have that property. Ohh, it should be `presenter._view`

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the CustomerID hidden in your View if not make it hidden in your view and i think it will fix the error

Comment: what do you mean sir?